# MySQL: Fatal Error encountered attempting to read the resultset

Tags: c#, mysql

Whenever my code runs, it works but then also crashes. I'm not sure if it is a time thing, or if another thing happens before that. The error code I get is this [image]

At first, I thought it was just my connect was being closed, but it was not. I'm not sure if it is my command text or what now and all the questions like this haven't been of help.

The code that I have is this

```
private void On_ProcessExit(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server has crashed...");
            _Proc.Exited -= new EventHandler(On_ProcessExit);

            DB.UpdateActivePID(ServerName, 0);

            if (_UserStop == true && _Proc.HasExited) {return; } //No need to restart server
            else if (_UserStop == false && _Proc.HasExited) //Need to restart the server
            {
                Start();
            }
        }


public static MySqlConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                if(connection == null)
                    Open();
                IsConnected();
                return connection;
            }
        }

public static MySqlCommand PrepareCommand(string query, object[] bindings)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bindings.Length; i++)
            {
                var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("?"));
                query = regex.Replace(query, "@param" + i, 1);
            }

            var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Prepare();
            int index = 0;
            foreach (object o in bindings)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param" + index, o);
                index++;
            }
            return cmd;
        }

  public static void ExecuteUpdate(string query, params object[] bindings)
        {
            if (Connection == null) return;

            MySqlCommand cmd = PrepareCommand(query, bindings);
            Console.WriteLine("SQL Line: " + cmd.CommandText);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
public static void UpdateActivePID(string serverName, int pid)
        {
            if (Connection == null) return;
            string query = "UPDATE ServerParameters SET ActivePID = ? WHERE ServerName = ?";
            ExecuteUpdate(query, new object[] { pid,serverName } );
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Sounds like `ExecuteNonQuery()` line throws exception. Can you provide full stack trace (in formatted text, not console image) for the exception?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I would have to type it out because it is on a remote server. If you truly think it will make that much of a difference, I will.

Comment: From the stack trace shown in console image, I found `ExecuteUpdate(query, new object[] { pid,serverName } );` line which calls `ExecuteUpdate`, and then calls `ExecuteNonQuery` which throwing exception. Check `cmd.CommandText` value to make sure that the query is valid.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto what I get echoed out is "SQL Line: UPDATE ServerParameters SET ActivePID = \@param0 WHERE ServerName = \@param1" as my command sql. **Tip - Don't include the back-slashes in, I just had to put something in front because SO thought I was trying to tag a user**

Comment: Where `MySqlConnection` with specified connection string has called? I think the problem is not in your query string, it is in the connection itself (previous connection with `DataReader` still open when trying to execute update query, the evidence is `ExecuteReader` exist on exception stack trace).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes, that had me confused because it should have had ExecuteReader anywhere. If you give me a few minutes, I will post my whole DB class and parts where it has critical interactions. Also on a side note, I did inspect my code where I do call a SELECT query and I do close those data readers when I am finished.

Comment: What MySQL Server version are you using? Do you have any kind of proxy or clustering setup?

Answer (score 1):

looks like a wrong `utf` datatype like using `utf8mb3_general_ci` instead of `utf8mb4_general_ci`